# Are there minimum hardware requirements for client-side rendering on the HOOPS Web Platform?

Tags: 3d, cad, video-card, hoops

I have started using the HOOPS Web Platform and I can't find what kind of hardware requirements are needed to interactively render 3D graphics (at any scale) on the client side.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We it certainly depends on the nature of the data rendered. You can image there will be different requirements for rendering a Lego brick vs. [a Boeing 777](https://cloud.techsoft3d.com/demos/boeing-777/).

[Client-Side Rendering](https://docs.techsoft3d.com/communicator/latest/build/prog_guide/servers/overview.html#toc_rendering) (CSR) uses WebGL in the browser and sufficient client side hardware (GPU) to render the data you expect to view.